# How to modify an element inside a span

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a span element performing an animation onload. Inside this span element there is another element that I would like to modify. I have tried to use CSS to do this but I can't access it without disrupting the animation.

Html

```
<span id="sometext"><a class="sd" href="#">Click here.</a></span>

<div id="btn">decrypt
    <div>
```

CSS

```
body {
width: 80%;
font-family: monospace;
background-color: #000;
}
.code {
color: #0a0;
word-break: break-all;
}
#sometext {
color: white;
}
.sd {
color: #000;
cursor: pointer;
}
#btn {
width: 60px;
height: 20px;
color: red;
padding: 15px;
border: #fff 2px solid;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/v9p34o1z/

All help appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to modify in this span?

Comment: The color of the text 'Click here' and add a link (now '#') without affecting the rest of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.text` to change the span, use `.html` otherwise the html is either stripped or rendered as text.

```
function animate(element, options) {
var text = element.html(),
    text_only = element.text(),
    span = $("<span/>").addClass(options.className).insertAfter(element),
    interval = options.duration / (text_only.length * options.stepsPerGlyph),
    step = 0,
    length = 0,
    stepper = function () {
        if (++step % options.stepsPerGlyph === 0) {
            length++;
            element.html(text.slice(0, length));
        }
        if (length <= text.length) {
            span.html(randomString(options.codeGlyphs, text_only.length - length));
            setTimeout(stepper, interval);
        } else {
            span.remove();
        }
    };
element.text("");
stepper();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem. I now have a problem with the animation loading strangely http://jsfiddle.net/pnrvg8uq/1/. Any advice here?

Comment: So to be clear, this wasn't the answer then? B1ll, Other users will see this as an answer and get misguided. Also you never specified anything about not altering the rest of the #somewhat line. You have to make things more clear next time and pick the correct answer. How would you feel if you search for an answer here and it wasn't? You are making newbie mistakes, that's ok. Just for next time :) good luck

Comment: I have modified the answer, it looks better, still not perfect though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do,
adding this to your css did not disrupt the animation (atleast for me)

```
#sometext {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to change .sd without modifying the rest of #sometext.

Answer (score 0):

To modify these texts, first wrap them up in a span tag so that you can target them. Then use CSS according and add the following line to the jquery

```
 $("#sometext").addClass("yellow");
```

Add this to the CSS and modify as needed

```
 .yellow{
     color:yellow !important;
 }
```

Check the **[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v9p34o1z/1/)**